# How to determine the memory layout of a process in Windows?

Tags: windows, memory

How can I determine what memory is accessible by a process, other than calling `ReadProcessMemory()` on every single byte/page/whatever to see if it wins or fails?

(I know it must be possible as several tools show this sort of information, e.g. IDA Pro debugger, WinHex, Sysinternals' Process Monitor, ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[VirtualQueryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366907(VS.85).aspx) is likely the function you want.