# Reading the start address and length  (virtual memory map) of a process

Tags: c, winapi

As started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215299/reading-a-process-memory#comment16363546_12215299)

I need to know how to read the start address and length (virtual memory map) of a process.

I would like to map a process memory. I would like to read values of a process memory and write values to them.

I'm curious about how programs like Cheat-O'matic (cheat-o-matic.softonic.com.br) work. First thing I thought was that the process would be loaded in a contiguous memory location. But that seems not right.

Comment: There's no such a thing as a "start address (and length) of a process", probably what you want is the virtual memory map.

Comment: What do you mean by start address and length? Start of what?

Comment: oKay,, eddited. Tell me if its clearer.

Comment: The virtual memory of a process is not a single contiguous block, so there is no single "start address" and "length". Why are you snooping on the virtual memory of another process anyway?

Comment: @RaymondChen - I would like to map a process memory. I would like to read values of a process memory and write values to it.

Comment: What is your scenario? Why do you think that reading and writing the memory of another process will solve your problem?

Comment: @RaymondChen - i'm just studing. I'm curious about how programs like Cheat-O'matic (cheat-o-matic.softonic.com.br) work. First thing I thought was that the process would be loaded in a contiguous memory location.

Comment: I would suggest that you develop your programming skills more generally rather than focusing on understanding how cheat engines work. Once you have a better understanding of programming and operating systems design, you will be able to answer these questions yourself.

Comment: "I thought was that the process would be loaded in a contiguous memory location" - "a process" is not a thing that you load in memory; as Raymond said, you should really study to understand better how OSes work before diving in this kind of things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the memory layout of a process in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398696/how-to-determine-the-memory-layout-of-a-process-in-windows) and [C ReadProcessMemory - how to examine the memory area associated with a process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330906/c-readprocessmemory-how-to-examine-the-memory-area-associated-with-a-process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call repeatedly [VirtualQueryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), starting with address zero and increasing each time of the value obtained in the `RegionSize` member of the `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure you passed to it. To obtain a meaningful map obviously the process should be paused.

Still, even after you got this memory map, I'm not sure what you can do with it: unless you know (by other means) the internals of the process you are accessing all you get to know is locations where you can read or write without triggering an access violation, not the meaning of their content. You should really clarify what you are trying to achieve, Read/WriteProcessMemory usually aren't a solution for "normal" problems.

Comment: I added a few lines in my question, trying to clarify.

Comment: What they're trying to achieve is the same thing as most people asking questions about very advanced and highly dubious  engineering practices (process snooping and patching, code injection): Cheating at video games. It's like somebody who takes an "Introduction to Electronics" class and then decides that their first project is to defuse a live bomb.

Comment: Well its a start, my start. I need start in some way. I have no teacher and no reference. And i have no pretention of being a professional. Im just curious. Nothing serious.

Comment: I would recommend that you start with a much less ambitious project.