# Information on the virtual memory my program is using?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, virtual-memory

Is there a way I can get information on the virtual memory my application is using?

As far as i'm aware there are several segments of memory that a program uses, such as code segment, data segments and the heap, stack etc.

Is there a way I can get information on the addresses where these segments start and end?

To give some context i'm trying to draw an image which contains a visual representation of the virtual memory of my program (a kind of graph). So i need the start and end addresses of the different segments, and if possible a way to determine if an address is memory is currently being used.

i'm using c++ on windows btw.

Comment: I remember my professor writing a program that catches SIGSEGVs and then goes and accesses addresses at multiples of 4kBs or so. This will only give you information which addresses are readable though, and I'm not sure how it'll work on Windows.

Comment: You'd need to be more specific on what you are looking for. If you are on 32-bit windows your are using 2^32 bytes of virtual memory. If you are are on 64-bit windows you are using 2^64 bytes of VIRTUAL memory (and even logical memory). Are you talking about the size of the working set? How many logical pages have been mapped?

Comment: There is nothing at the language level to determine this. You  must use OS specific libraries to query your OS state and the state of the processes.

Comment: @user334403 Okay, bear with me, because i'm a little lost on some of things you are talking about as i've only just started learning this. I'm using 64-bit windows but my program is 32 bit. If by 'working set' you mean pyshical memory then no i'm on about the 4gb of virtual memory. And if that's not what you mean by working set then i don't know sorry. And i don't know what you mean by logical pages being mapped, sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading the virtual memory map of a process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215719/reading-the-start-address-and-length-virtual-memory-map-of-a-process)

Answer (score 1):

You can query memory layout of a process by calling `VirtualQueryEx`.
It returns the memory map layout you wanted.

The returned `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` table list of sections of memory with their protection attributes.

However, the machine works on protection attributes not by its nature(code, data, rodata, bss, heap, etc), you can only *guess* on them:

- PAGE_EXECUTE: code
- PAGE_READONLY: rodata
- PAGE_READWRITE: data, bss, heap, stack
- PAGE_WRITECOPY: data, bss, heap, stack

However, the above guess would not be reliable if the process did it's own customized VirtualAllocate or file mapping, to increase the accurancy you may also query the executable name with `GetModuleFileName` and parse the file, then compare with the table (note the address space randomization)

Comment: Thanks, do you have any examples of how this is used? When i use it the information it returns isn't that helpful? any help is appreciated.