# C++ is there a way to find all memory addresses that contain a specific value

Tags: c++, memory, memory-address

I want to know if there is a way to print all the memory addresses of a process with an offset that contains a specific value.

The final output looks something like this.

```
Current process test.exe
Address + offset
0x84364785 + 1C = 100
0x76352478 + 1C = 100
0x53683625 + 1C = 100
```

Current Operating system is Windows 10 and the application is 32bit

Comment: On windows you can use a windows API function to return information about the memory pages of the current process: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009927/information-on-the-virtual-memory-my-program-is-using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009927/information-on-the-virtual-memory-my-program-is-using)

Comment: Why I mentioned that is for 2 reasons 1. a 64 bit virtual address space is huge and 2. if you access a page of memory that you don't have the proper permission (at least read access) your OS will throw some type of OS exception and may just shut down your process.

Comment: Not only that, but if you access a page of memory you do have access to, even just for reading, but that page is protected by page guards, for instance, you can cause all kinds of headaches for the other program, leading to unexpected side effects, memory corruption, crashes, etc. You can't just go rummaging around willy-nilly in random areas of another program's memory space. You need to be more targeted with your accesses.

Comment: On embedded systems, assign a pointer with an address then dereference it.  Note that not all addresses are readable or exist (decoded).  Some addresses may return garbage.  Some address lines may be multiplexed as GPIO or other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest restriction to this is on modern system, programs are restricted from accessing memory they don't own. This is a security issue if errant programs can overwrite other programs.

This was possible on some older systems. You could just set a variable to a starting address, test the value there, then increment the address and so on.

But trying this in, say, Windows would quickly shut down your application for invalid memory access.

Comment: It's doable. Just not with pointers. You have to deliberately ask the operating system - look up `ReadProcessMemory`

Comment: @user253751: I didn't mean to say it wasn't possible. The OP has said nothing about what platform he's working on. My point was simply that the approach I described would quickly fail on Windows, for example.